# Correlated subqueries- Codeacademy

Tags: sql

Learning SQL through `codeacademy`. The example is a flights table;
For instance, assuming flight_id increments with each additional flight, we could use the following query to view flights by carrier, flight id, and sequence number:

```
SELECT carrier, id,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM flights f
     WHERE f.id < flights.id
       AND f.carrier = flights.carrier) + 1 AS flight_sequence_number
FROM flights;
```

I am not understanding the function of the 'f' after flights. Also what does f.carrier= flights.carrier mean?
If someone could shed some light that would be great!

Comment: It's not a function. It is alias of this table name

Comment: Have different table aliases for flights to make things much clearer. (E.g. f1 and f2.)

Comment: This can be done a lot more efficiently using window functions.

Comment: This is the code that codeacademy is teaching me to use. If anyone has any better websites for me to learn from please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Give your tables aliases as you will lose track as your queries grow.

```
SELECT f.carrier, f.id, (SELECT COUNT(*)
                         FROM flights fs
                         WHERE fs.id < f.id
                         AND fs.carrier = f.carrier) + 1 AS flight_sequence_number
FROM flights f;
```

Answer (score 0):

`f` is a table alias, used to distinguish the references to `flights` in the inner and the outer queries.  I would normally use `f` for the outer query and `f2` for the inner query:

```
SELECT f.carrier, f.id,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) + 1
        FROM flights f2
        WHERE f2.id < f.id AND f2.carrier = f.carrier
       ) AS flight_sequence_number
FROM flights f;
```

As a note, this is a ridiculous and old-fashioned way of doing this calculation.  ANSI SQL supports a simple function to do this:

```
SELECT f.carrier, f.id,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY f.carrier ORDER BY f.id) as  flight_sequence_number
FROM flights f;
```